# .Net: how can I have a combobox with multitple fields of its data source as Displaymember?

Tags: .net, user-interface, combobox

How can I have a combobox with multiple fields of its data source as its display member without adding additional columns to its data source?

I mean I wanna to have a combobox with displaymember like "ID" + "-" "Name" .
1 - Black
2 - White
3 - Red

I  DO NOT  want to add additional column to its data source.

Thank you

Comment: Could you explain in more detail, e.g. with an example?

Comment: ok, suppose we have a table in Sql server called table1.
table1 has 2 columns : ID and Name.
==
table1:
1  Black
2  White
3  Red
I wanna to populate a combobox on my form with a data table named tb1 in a way that the displaymember property of my combobox  be "ID" + " - " + "Name".

Answer (score 1):

Binding to multiple properties is not supported (in WinForms). You have to extend your `DataTable` with a computed column and bind to this new column.

```
dataTable.Columns.Add("IdAndName", typeof(String), "ID + Name");

comboBox.DataSource = dataTable;
comboBox.DisplayMember = "IdAndName";
```

See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) for reference on valid expressions for computed columns. Maybe you have to use `Convert`.

```
dataTable.Columns.Add("IdAndName", typeof(String), "Convert(ID, 'System.String') + Name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a select statement to get out the data rather than just get everything from the table and write something like:

```
SELECT ID, STR(ID) + ' - ' + Name DisplayName FROM table1
```

Then set ID as the data member and DisplayName as the display member.

Untested, but feels like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Options:
1) Modify your Data Call to include the combined column, i.e. you wouldn't be "adding" a column per se, you'd be selecting the two columns as stated by **ho**
2) Switch to a ListView 
3) Add the results of your data call to a collection class which has the fields you want to display (ID, DisplayName) and add a "IDDisplayNameCombined" property which combines them and bind this collection to the combobox and use the new combined property as the displaymember

Answer (score 0):

I just found a cool solution to this same problem and I thought I'd put it here.
If you don't set the `DisplayMemeber` the ComboBox will call the ToString method of yous source objects. So all you need to do is overriding the `ToString` method, and voilá!

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0} - {1}", ID, Name);
}
```

Hope it helps!